# I am not sure between which two elements I should be looking to scrape and formatting error (jupyter + selenium)

Tags: selenium, selenium-webdriver, web-scraping, jupyter-notebook, selenium-chromedriver

I finally got around to displaying the page that I need in text/HTML and did conclude that the data I need is also included. For now I just have it printing the entire page because I remain conflicted between the two elements that I potentially need to get what I want. Between these three highlighted elements [1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dTSw5.png), [2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/c6En9.png), and [3](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4FGLr.png), I am having trouble with first identifying which one I should reference (*I would go with the 'table' element but it doesn't highlight the left most column with ticker names which is literally half the point of getting this data, though the name is referenced like [so](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ho6RM.png) as shown in the highlighted yellow part*). Also, the class descriptions seem really long and and sometimes appears to have two within the same elements so I was wondering how I would address that? And though this problem is not as immediate, if you did take that code and just printed it and scrolled a bit down, the table data is in straight columns so I was wondering if that would be addressed after I reference the proper element or have to write something additional to fix it? Would the fact that I have multiple pages to scan also change anything in the code? Thank you in advance!

Code:

```
!pip install selenium
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
from urllib.request import urlopen, Request
from selenium import webdriver
import pandas as pd

driver = webdriver.Chrome("D:/chromedriver/chromedriver.exe")
driver.get('https://www.barchart.com/options/unusual-activity/stocks')
soup = BeautifulSoup(driver.page_source, 'html.parser')


# get text
text = soup.get_text()

print(text)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

## edit

### `read_html` without bs4

You wont need `beautifulsoup` to get your goal, `pandas` is selecting all html tables from the page source and push them into a `list` of `data frames`.

In your case there is only one table in the page source, so you get your `df` by selecting the first element in `list` by slicing with `[0]`:

```
df = pd.read_html(driver.page_source)[0]
```

**Example**

```
from selenium import webdriver
import pandas as pd

driver = webdriver.Chrome('D:/chromedriver/chromedriver.exe')
driver.get('https://www.barchart.com/options/unusual-activity/stocks')

df = pd.read_html(driver.page_source)[0]

driver.close()
```

---

### Initial answer based on bs4

Your close to a solution, let `pandas` take control and read the html prettified and bs4 flavored to `pandas` and modify it there to your needs:

```
pd.read_html(soupt_one('table').prettify(), flavor='bs4')
```

**Example**

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
from selenium import webdriver
import pandas as pd

driver = webdriver.Chrome('D:/chromedriver/chromedriver.exe')
driver.get('https://www.barchart.com/options/unusual-activity/stocks')
soup = BeautifulSoup(driver.page_source, 'html.parser')

df = pd.read_html(soup.select_one('table').prettify(), flavor='bs4')[0]

df
```

Comment: Does this imply I would use the "3" picture's element then? Assuming so, would I have to copy-paste the entire description for the class and its name (yellow tinted words, blue tinted words)?

Comment: Yes it does and you can also select it by its `attributes` but there is no need to do that, cause it is the only table on that website. Take a look at my edit and check out the more generic approach without 'bs4`.